# Loading extra fields for update in Django dependent dropdown list

Tags: python, django, drop-down-menu

I implemented a dependent dropdown on my Django webapp. I used this tutorial [Implementing dependent drop down](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/01/29/how-to-implement-dependent-or-chained-dropdown-list-with-django.html). However, challenge comes when I want to update the form. To put this in perspective, let me recreate the code here.

Model.py

```
class VehicleMake(models.Model):
    make = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    manufacturer = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.make


class VehicleModel(models.Model):
    make = models.ForeignKey(VehicleMake, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    model_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.model_name

class Vehicle(models.Model):
    model = models.ForeignKey(VehicleModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    description = models.TextField()
```

Notice that unlike in the provided tutorial, I don't have both of the dependent fields on the vehicle model. That is to avoid repetition since if you know the vehicle model, you will definitely know the make from the `VehicleModel` table.

Here is the form:

forms.py

```
class VehicleDetails(forms.ModelForm):
    make = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=VehicleMake.objects.all(),
                                    empty_label="Select Vehicle Make")
    class Meta:
        model = Vehicle
        fields = ['make', 'model', 'description'
        ]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        super(VehicleDetails, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields['model'].queryset = VehicleModel.objects.none()

        if 'make' in self.data:
            try:
                make = int(self.data.get('make'))
                self.fields['model'].queryset = VehicleModel.objects.filter(make=make).order_by('model_name')
            except (ValueError, TypeError):
                pass  # invalid input from the client; ignore and fallback to empty VehicleModel queryset
        elif self.instance.pk:
            vehicle_model = VehicleModel.objects.get(self.instance.model)
            self.fields['make'] = vehicle_model.make
            self.fields['model'].queryset = self.instance.model_set.filter(make=vehicle_model.make).order_by('model_name')
```

So, my challenge is, when I want to update the form, I get an error from the last section of the form under the `elif` code. I want to get the value of `make` using the store value of `model` then use that to render the form of course with the select of options of `model` being those from the selected `make`, unless the user now makes changes to the `make` field.

This is what I have tried so far (especially under the `elif` section on the `forms.py`) but I keep getting the error: `TypeError: 'VehicleModel' object is not iterable`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by changing this in the `elif` block:

```
vehicle_model = VehicleModel.objects.get(pk=self.instance.model.id)
self.fields['make'].queryset = self.instance.model.make.__class__.objects.all()
self.fields['model'].queryset = self.instance.model.__class__.objects.filter(make=vehicle_model.make).order_by('model_name')
```

Then all I had to do at the `views.py` to ensure that current value is loaded was to add a `initial` value while loading the form, i.e.

```
vehicle_form = VehicleDetails(instance=listing.vehicle, initial = {'make': listing.vehicle.model.make })
```

I hope it helps anyone in the same problem.